# Foursquare log-in

Tags: android

i am developing an android application for foursquare.I have gone through every api endpoints,experimented with it.I know how to access data using api endpoints and access token.

Now what my application requires is a log-in page containing username password.

I use the following url for obtaining access token for a user.

```
https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate
?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=MY_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
```

when i post the above url in the browser i am 1st redirected to the foursquare login page then after log-in i am directed to MY_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI with the access token appended to it.
if i follow this procedure then my log-in page is a waste.

Is there any way by which i can append the username and password to above url directly and bypass foursquare log-in page in my application?

can any1 help me out with this?

I only require a proper log-in page.

And 1 more thing i wanted to know is that after user log-in how to get user's foursquare ID from username and password?

Comment: If you want to use WebView, take a look on how Facebook SDK does it (FbDialog.java). To put it short - as redirect uri they use their 'own' protocol "fb://" (or something similar) and intercept it to grab returned access token (and not follow redirect).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do plain-text authentication. You have to use the OAuth2 procedure.

This is a security measure as it's more secure for the user than allowing you to handle their username and password directly.

So, if you want to have your own login page in your app it will have to be separate credentials to the user's foursquare credentials. Then you could have them 'link' their accounts, instead of using foursquare to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this project on github. It uses android webview to capture users oauth token.
https://github.com/condesales/easyFoursquare4Android